# Use Gaussian distribution to calculate an integral

Tags: integration

I have to solve an integral using another one that is given to me:

[Discription](http://i42.tinypic.com/209t3ww.png)

The given equation has to be manipulated until the integral we want is derived.

My problem is that I can't find a way to decouple $-x^2$ and $2\sigma^2$ from the exponent. Is there a formula that I can use for this or some pointers I can use? (The teacher said it's a really easy one but I have spent almost $3$ hours on it).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Am I allowed to use whatever value I want for σ?

Comment: Almost, except $\sigma=0$. You were given the general result. In the probability context, $\sigma\gt 0$, but that does not affect the integral, since it uses $\sigma^2$.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I thought it was much more complicated :D